# getting Error msg: List index out of range while slicing a list?

Tags: python

I would like to slice entries from a list `index` and then insert the sliced entries into a new list `f_index`. Unfortunately I receive the error message below:

> `the list index is out of range.`

The counting variable i is stopped at `129`. The list `index` has a total of `973` entries, and i need to slice them all.

Since this is my first question, feel free to give me feedback on how I can ask better questions in the future.

**The Code**

```
f_index = []
i = 0

for eachindex in index:
    
    f_index.append((str(index[i]).split('--')[1].split(';')[0]))
    
    i= i +1 
  
print(f_index)
```

**Output error**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-f0d0c9347c8a> in <module>
      8 for eachindex in index:
      9 
---> 10     f_index.append((str(index[i]).split('--')[1].split(';')[0]))
     11 
     12     i= i +1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What does the list `index` look like ? its data

Comment: can you support the index list so we can see the items of the list this well help us to debug your code

Comment: The whole list is too long, but here is a short overview: ```[['ACCO;NUM;ACCO -- Acceptances Outstanding;;'], ['ACCRT;NUM;ACCRT -- ARO Accretion Expense;;'],```

Comment: @smnlscae - what is the final form of `f_index` ? what you want to acheieve ? give us an examples of the desired output

Comment: The exact problem is probably at least one of the sublists that doesn't contain a string containing `--`, but there are some other problematic things about this code.

Comment: Firstly, you are looping using `eachindex` (which you are not using), and then constructing an index variable `i` by hand. It'll work, but it would be easier to either loop explicitly over index `for i in range(len(index)):` - or if you want both `i` and `eachindex` inside your loop then do `for i, eachindex in enumerate(index):`

Comment: @Adam The final output of ```f_index ``` should be ```Acceptances Outstanding```. I just want to cut off the abbreviations and ```--``` and also the semicolons at the end.

Comment: Secondly, the elements of `index` are 1-element lists of strings, rather than strings. Rather than converting the list into a string (with `str(index[i])`), you probably want to extract that one element using `index[i][0]`

Comment: @alaniwi you're right. The entry that would come next contains no ```--```.

Comment: @smnlscae Then you need to decide what you are going to do with those, because if you try to split on `'--'` but the string does not contain `'--'` then you will get a one-element list and then when you try to extract the second element of that list, you get the `IndexError` that you observed.

Comment: @alaniwi Are there any alternatives where I can split?

Comment: @smnlscae Please post your 'bad' record.

Comment: @subnivean  ['CIK;CHAR;CIK Number;;'] This one is causing trouble.

Comment: @smnlscae That looks like your column headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your index is not type of iterable object. you can check it by following code :

```
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable
>>> isinstance(index , Iterable)
```

and result will be True/False.

strings,arrays,collections,tuples are iterable and number is not iterable, for example:

```
>>> name = "ali"
>>> isinstance(name, Iterable)
True
>>> number = 12
>>> isinstance(number, Iterable)
False
```

*Code tested on  Python version 3.8.3

for more information about iterable objects see [this](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html).

Comment: I checked and the result is True.

Comment: We in fact know that is a list, but even if it was not an object that supported indexing, this would not explain an `IndexError` (it would be `TypeError` instead).

Comment: @smnlsca it seems that your object is not splitable to -- or ; characters, instead of one line code break your code into three line as a ```splitToDash = (str(index[i]).split('--')``` and ```splitToComma = SplitToLine[1].split(';')``` and ``` f_index.append(splitToComma[0])``` to see your error line

Answer (score 0):

Is this a job for a nice, pythonic list comprehension?

```
index = [['ACCO;NUM;ACCO -- Acceptances Outstanding;;'],
         ['ACCRT;NUM;ACCRT -- ARO Accretion Expense;;']]

f_index = [rec[0].split(' -- ')[1].split(';')[0] for rec in index]
print(f_index)

['Acceptances Outstanding', 'ARO Accretion Expense']
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the `IndexError` that the OP is seeing, though. My hypothesis is that one of the `split('--')` calls is returning only a 1-element list (`'--'` not found) and the `[1]` is failing, because I can't see why either of the other two indexes in the original post would fail. Probably an exception trap will be needed to deal with this, which suggests that it would be more convenient to use an explicit loop rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: Although I suppose you could add `if ' -- ' in rec[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your index `list` looks like,

```
[['ACCO;NUM;ACCO -- Acceptances Outstanding;;'], ['ACCRT;NUM;ACCRT -- ARO Accretion Expense;;'],......]
```

which means, list of lists while the inner lists are folowing the format:

```
['<letters>;<letters>;<letters> -- <letters> <letters> <letters>;;']
```

```
f_index =[]
for inner_list in index:
    temp=inner_list[0].split('--')
    temp=temp[1].split()
    acc,out=temp[0].strip(),temp[1].strip().strip(';;')
    f_index .append([acc,out])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I have removed the problematic entry manually and now it runs.

Comment: This is not an answer.